# Is there any way to replace/substitute an array data points in uint8 data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, uint8t

I have this data

```
old= array([[171, 171, 171, ..., 170, 170, 170],
       [171, 171, 171, ..., 170, 170, 170],
       [171, 171, 171, ..., 170, 170, 170],
       ...,
       [ 17,  17,  17, ...,  17,  17,  17],
       [ 17,  17,  17, ...,  17,  17,  17],
       [ 17,  17,  17, ...,  17,  17,  17]], dtype=uint8)
```

in this data i need to put my external array data points

```
new= array([ 65, 108, 105,  32, 105, 115,  32, 116, 104, 101,  32,  66, 101,
       115, 116,  32, 105, 110,  32, 116, 104, 101,  32, 119, 111, 114,
       108, 100,  32, 121, 101, 101, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104,
       104])
```

in the first row of the old array such that output is like

```
 old= array([[  65, 108, 105,  32, 105, 115,  32, 116, 104, 101,  32,66,101,
       115, 116,  32, 105, 110,  32, 116, 104, 101,  32, 119, 111, 114,
       108, 100,  32, 121, 101, 101, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104,
       104, ..., 170, 170, 170],
       [171, 171, 171, ..., 170, 170, 170],
       [171, 171, 171, ..., 170, 170, 170],
       ...,
       [ 17,  17,  17, ...,  17,  17,  17],
       [ 17,  17,  17, ...,  17,  17,  17],
       [ 17,  17,  17, ...,  17,  17,  17]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: What's the `shape` of `old` and `new`?

Comment: old shape is (1080,1000) 
and 
new shape is (40,)

Comment: Have you read the `numpy` docs about indexing?  How would you display the first 40 values of the first row of `old`?

Comment: thats the problem .. can this be solvable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
old[0, :len(new)] = new
```

Comment: see the question not slicing i want to substitute values of of new array in old's first row array

Comment: That's what `= new` is for, is it not?

Comment: i dont know what are u saying.....but this ur answer is not working for me

Comment: my bad.. i m extremely sorry  .. that was amaxing.. can u explain this to me sir?

Comment: As you said, it's simply slicing. However, numpy allows new values assignment with slicing just as the code shows.

Comment: why we cant use replace in pyhton ?

Answer (score 1):

To replace the first row of your array:

`old[0] = new`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using numpy? Does

```
old[0] = new[0]
```

work? (Assuming you wanted to replace the first row of the old array with 
the first row of the new array)